# Existence of $\xi_1, \; \xi_2$ for a function $f$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function defined as: $f(x)=e^{1-x} \ln x+e^{1-x}-1$.
Prove that there exist $\xi_1, \; \xi_2 \in (1, e) $ such that $\dfrac{f'(\xi_1)}{f(\xi_2)}=\dfrac{e-1}{2015}$.

I proved that $f(1)=0$ and that $f$ is not monotonic on $(0, +\infty)$ but for this question I am stuck. May I have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$f'(x)=-e^{1-x}\ln x+\frac{e^{1-x}}{x}-e^{1-x}=e^{1-x}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\ln x-1\right)$$

Thus gives
$$f(1)=0,f'(1)=0$$
and
$$f(e)=2e^{1-e}-1=(2e-e^{e})e^{-e}<\frac{1}{2015}(1-e)e^{-e}<0$$
$$f'(e)=(1-2e)e^{-e}<-e^{-e}<0$$

Note that both $f,f'$ are continuous on $[1,e]$, thus by intermediate value theorem, there are $\xi_1,\xi_2\in(1,e)$ s.t.
$$f'(\xi_1)=\frac{1}{2015}(1-e)e^{-e},\quad f(\xi_2)=-e^{-e}$$

Comment: Thank you.. It was not trivial afterall... Good day!

Comment: You're welcome.